# Can I rotate a symbol based on a feature attribute?

Tags: geotools

I have a "point-layer" wich has an attribute "Direction". How do I create a PointSymbolizer that reads the feature attribute "Direction", and uses it as rotation for each point-symbol?

```
List<GraphicalSymbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
symbols.add(graphic);
Mark mark = sf.createMark(ff.literal("triangle"),
   stroke, 
   fill, 
   ff.literal(size), 
   ff.literal(0)//Rotation ?
); 
symbols.add(mark);
Graphic symbol = sf.graphic(symbols, 
    ff.literal(1.0), 
    ff.literal(size), 
    ff.literal(0), //Rotation?
    sf.anchorPoint(ff.literal(0.5),ff.literal(0.5)), 
    null
);
pointSym =  sf.createPointSymbolizer(symbol, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

```
ff.property("Direction")
```